# Strange behaviour of tabcontrol in Windows, all tabs appear twice

Tags: c#, mono, tabcontrol

running this in linux, all fine.
running in Windows making trouble, all tabs are twice present and i can't insert content into tabs.

https://abload.de/img/unbenannt82jfh.png

someone knows about?

```
public class CalendarApp : Form {
    public CalendarApp() : base() {

        tabControl = new TabControl();
        tabPages = new TabPage[3];
        string []tabText = {"Haupt", "Kontakte", "Termine"};
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Ahhh windoof: {0}", i);
            tabPages[i]=new TabPage();
            tabPages[i].Text = tabText[i];
            tabPages[i].TabIndex = i;
            tabPages[i].Parent = tabControl;
            tabControl.Controls.Add(tabPages[i]);
        }


        FlowLayoutPanel mainPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        tabControl.Size = new Size(mainPanel.Size.Width+8, mainPanel.Size.Height+24);
        this.Text = "CalendarApp";
        Controls.Add (tabControl);
        AutoSize=true;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        ResumeLayout(false);
        PerformLayout();
    }


    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() {
        Application.Run(new CalendarApp());
    }

    private TabControl tabControl;
    private TabPage []tabPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i've yust found the Problem:

//          tabPages[i].Parent = tabControl; <-this Line is causing the Problem
            tabControl.Controls.Add(tabPages[i]);